# Why this input box doesnt fire the focus event on IE?

Tags: jquery, html, css, input, focus

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/y4dkF/4/) is my code :

## HTML

```
<div style="position:relative;">  
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:40;" class="textBoxColor">My <span style='color:#c83243;'>custom</span> text</div>        
    <input type="text" style="position: relative; z-index: 50;" class="textBoxEmpty">          
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.textBoxEmpty, .textBoxColor
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    line-height:20px;   
    font-size:20px;
    height:20px;
    width:340px;
    color:#000000;
    background-color:Transparent;
}
```

## jQuery

```
$(".textBoxEmpty").focus(function() {
    $(this).css('background', '#ffffff');
});
```

clicking on the "input" (over the text) I can't focus the input. But if I click near the text (to the right) it get the focus!

Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: It's working fine for me in Chromium 16. What browser are you using?

Comment: Silly me... I should learn to read.

Comment: Code from the question in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/fHLex/

Comment: @Matt Gibson : 7,8,9....on each...

Comment: nnnnnn : I already posted the fiddle...check my question (near This...)

Comment: the problem is not focu/jquery, is html/css! I'll open a new question! Can you delete this?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this:

```
.textBoxEmpty:focus, .textBoxColor:focus {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

and you all set.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the CSS ':focus' pseudo rather than using jQuery to manipulate the DOM

For simple changes such as background color this will be more efficient

Comment: too much big troubles with CSS and browsers (opera...safari...IE)...that's why I use jquery...

Comment: It's a convenience feature anyway so if it doesn't work in ancient browsers - who cares.

Comment: I care...people who use those ancient browsers care... we must care about this...